# Does headless Chrome auto update?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless, automatic-updates

Does Chrome update itself when running in headless mode by selenium?

It seems, it is not updating, probably because of `--disable-background-networking` switch set by Selenium by default. I want to ensure that's indeed the case. If there any reference in documentation explaining either auto-update behavior or meaning of switches and their impact? So far best I've found is list with all [command line Chrome switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) with some comments, but it is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, *Chrome Browser Client* doesn't update itself when running in headless mode by selenium.

As per [**`Getting Started with Headless Chrome`**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) the [**`Headless Chrome`**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) is the server environment where you don't need a visible UI shell.

If you've got Chrome 59+ installed, you start Chrome with the `--headless` flag as follows:

```
chrome \
  --headless \                   # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
  --disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
```

`chrome` should always point to your installation of **`Chrome`**. Of course, the exact location varies from platform to platform.

So until and unless the original **Chrome Browser** is *automatically*/*manually* updated, *Chrome Browser Client* doesn't get updated.

---

### TL;DR

**`--disable-background-networking`** is configured to disable several subsystems which run *network requests* in the background. This is used when performing *network performance testing* in order to avoid noise in the measurements.

Comment: I meant the Chrome browser itself. I guess if I just copy "Application" folder from Chrome installation to server, which wouldn't include auto-updater binaries and it will not update itself.

Comment: @dlxeon I am afraid as I won't be able to guide you properly on _copy "Application" folder from Chrome installation_ but that must not be as per the _best practices_. In such a requirement you can look at _Chrome Portable_